# Parallelogram area using determinant

Tags: geometry, determinant

Given a Parallelogram with the co-ordinates: $(a+c, b+d), (c,d), (a, b)$ and $(0, 0)$

I have to prove that the area of the Parallelogram is:
$|ad-bc|$ as in the determinant of:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\ 
c & d
\end{bmatrix}$$

How do I even begin using the concept of determinants for this geometrical question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, show that the transformation of the points of the unit square map to the parallelogram that you show.  Secondly, calculate the area of a parallelogram using some basic symmetries of the shape and show it is $|a d - b c|$.  This is in fact the basic principle behind determinants, they were invented to see how the area of shapes change under a matrix transformation.

How you show the area depends on what you already know.  If you know about complex numbers, think about what the imaginary part of $\bar{z_1} z_2$ represents.

Comment: I honestly did not understand what you meant by: "Firstly, show that the transformation of the points of the unit square map to the parallelogram that you show."

Comment: Oh.  there are 4 points on the unit square
    (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)
Calculate what happens when the matrix multiplies each of these vectors.

Comment: https://tube.geogebra.org/m/40980 and https://tube.geogebra.org/m/615071 are somewhat useful illustrations. See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_Definitions_of_Complex_Cross_Product for the complex numbers analogy.

Answer (score 1):

Try finding the area of the parallelogram via Heron's formula and then show that it is equal to the determinant of the corresponding matrix.