# Determinant: signed area of parallelogram question

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to understand the geometrical aspects of the determinant and have questions.  [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) states that:

$\begin{vmatrix} a \ b \\ c \ d \end{vmatrix} = ad - bc$

is the area of this parallelogram:

[image: a]

How is this area established?  I'm reading [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram) on parallelograms and do not see how the determinant equals the area.

I see [in another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336999/parallelogram-area-using-determinant) someone suggests using [Heron's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) to prove $A_p = ad - bc$.  Wiki later says:

Signed Area = $|u||v| sin \theta = |u^\Gamma||v| cos \theta' = \begin{bmatrix} -b \\ a \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} c \\ d \end{bmatrix} = ad - bc$, where $u = (a, b)$ and $u^\Gamma = (-b, a)$ is of the complementary angle to a perpendicular vector.

Does anyone know why $u^\Gamma = (-b, a)$?  I'm unable to understand this.  I think the coordinates are swapped to provide the same result with $cos$ as $sin$, but am confused by the $-$ sign.

Comment: Do you know the cross product? if you know the vector cross product It is easy to understand proof of the area of triangle and parallelgram

Comment: There is a much cleaner argument available. You can prove that the signed area is a bilinear function in the two vectors $(a, b), (c, d)$, and that it vanishes if they're parallel. It suffices then to compute the signed area for a single pair such as $(1, 0), (0, 1)$.

Comment: You can also find the area by splitting the parallelogram into two congruent triangles and using $A = \frac{1}{2} ab sin C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iamge is the original image with the original
parallelogram completed into an
$(a+c)\times(b+d)$ rectangle by adding two $b\times c$
rectangles, two $a\times b$ right triangles, and two
$c\times d$ right triangles.
The area of the parallelogram is thus
$$ (a\!+\!c)(b\!+\!d) - 2(b\,c) -
 2\Big(\frac12 a\,b+\frac12 c\, d\Big)
 = a\, d-b\, c.\tag{1}$$

[image]

Your question regarding $\,u^\Gamma = (-b,a)\, $
is answered by noting that it is
$\,u\,$ rotated by $\,90^\circ\,$ which is confirmed
by $\,u^\Gamma\cdot u = -b\,a+a\,b =  0.\,$

Comment: How do you reform the equation for the step to $ad - bc$?

Comment: @Nick In equation $(1)$ I used elementary algebra.